# How to switch to GUI mode form console mode in Suse Linux Enterprise Server 10?

Tags: suse

I want to switch to GUI mode from terminal interface in SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 and How to set GUI interface to default mode.

Comment: Thanx..it works...

Comment: Due to lack of information in your question we can't really figure out what's wrong. You can have a headless installation, mistakenly switched to tty, or just lack a proper display manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To switch to Console mode Press ‘Ctrl + Alt + F1' (F2 -- F6) To switch between consoles in Console mode Press ‘Alt + F1' (F2 -- F6) To switch to GUI mode Press ‘Alt + F7'